# Create a floating bar in HighCharts cloud

Tags: charts, highcharts, cloud

I've had a request form a client to have the following chart replicated in HighCharts cloud, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to make the first series show as a "floating gray bar" - or whatever it's called. Any suggestions on how I could achieve to this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `columnrange` series type to add the 'floating bar':

```
series: [{
    type: 'column',
    data: [...]
}, {
    type: 'columnrange',
    data: [...]
}]
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ys1x79uk/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.columnrange.data

Comment: Thanks @ppotaczek - that certainly renders the "floating" option I'm after, but I need it as a single value and not the range.

I've kinda hacked it by setting it as a line series and enabling point markers. Then I reduced the line size to 0 and left the point markers in place - the only problem is they are square and I need rectangle markers. Just trying to render them as rectangles is proving tricky.

Comment: Hi @Jon Wunder, In this case you need to define your own `symbol`, please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xze9o6ks/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek - that's brilliant, just what I'm after. Thanks heaps!